# Mockk: no answer found for a mocked JPA call with partial matching?

Tags: kotlin, jpa, junit, mockito, mockk

I'm trying to write a Junit test case for an update API. The API is using `saveAll` method of JPA to perform updates. The API is working fine, but when trying to mock the `saveAll` method it is giving me the following error:

> io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: UserRepository(#1).saveAll(userdetails..)

```
 @Test
 fun testUpdateUserDetailsSuccess() {
   val userRepository = mockk<UserRepository>()

   every { userRepository.saveAll(anyList()) } returns getUserDetailsTestData();

   val userDetailsDatabaseAdapter = UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter(userRepository)
   val userResponse = userDetailsDatabaseAdapter.updateUserDetails(getUserDetails())
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<UserDetails, UUID> {
    fun findById(userId: UUID): List<UserDetails>
}
```

**UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter**

```
    override suspend fun updateUserDetails(userDetail: UserDetails): Either<CustomError, Int> =
            either {
      
//fetching some details from DB and then forming a list of userDetails

    val response = updateUserDetails(
                    userRepository,
                    userDetails
                ) andThen ::mapToCount
    response.bind()
    }
```

**UpdateUserDetails**

```
fun updateUserDetails(
    userRepo: UserRepository,
    userDetails: List<UserDetails>
): Either<CustomError, List<UserDetails>> =
    bulkWriteToDatabase {
        userRepo.saveAll(userDetails)
    }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: You need to add the code of both `UserRepository` and `UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter`. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get you.Can you give an example

Comment: I was actually asking you to add the code of both `UserRepository` and `UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter` to your question so that we can help you further.

Comment: As I wrote previously @Harmeet Kaur, we need the code of both UserRepository and UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Tried to add as much code as I can. Please have a look @JoãoDias

Comment: Where is the second `updateUserDetails()` method defined and called? I can't actually find that in your question.

Comment: Corrected the code

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using the Mockito tag, but you're using Mockk.

Is that `anyList()` coming from `Mockito.anyList` by any chance?
If so, you're mixing [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) and [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) libraries.

Instead, can you try replacing Mockito's `anyList()` with Mockk's `any()` for partial matching:

```kotlin
 @Test
 fun testUpdateUserDetailsSuccess() {
   val userRepository = mockk<UserRepository>()

   every { userRepository.saveAll(any()) } returns getUserDetailsTestData();

   val userDetailsDatabaseAdapter = UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter(userRepository)
   val userResponse = userDetailsDatabaseAdapter.updateUserDetails(getUserDetails())
}
```

See: [Mockk - Partial argument matching](https://mockk.io/#partial-argument-matching)

---

Comment: If I try to do it as you suggested. A compilation error is shown "Not enough information to infer type variable T"

Comment: I see, is this the same problem as the question above or a different one? (i.e. is it a MockKException, seems to me like your test has progressed to a different unrelated error?)

If it's related, can you share the stack trace of the error produced in your question? If not can you can open another question (if needed) with further details please, and I am more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following (mind the `any()` and the assign of `getUserDetailsTestData()` to a variable):

```kotlin
@Test
fun testUpdateUserDetailsSuccess() {
  val userRepository = mockk<UserRepository>()
  val userDetails = getUserDetailsTestData()

  every { userRepository.saveAll(any()) } returns userDetails

  val userDetailsDatabaseAdapter = UserDetailsDatabaseAdapter(userRepository)
  val userResponse = userDetailsDatabaseAdapter.updateUserDetails(getUserDetails())
}
```

Comment: Tried to do the same but didn't work for me